# Non-latin characters don't work with @font-face

Tags: html, css, font-face

I'm trying to import a font file into my website and non-latin are not working.

When using [Font Squirrel webfont generator](https://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator) I have selected an expert option that allows me to select non-western characters.

I tested the .woff file with Font Forge and the characters that I need are supported.

I have added the

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
```

HTML tag.

All the font filenames are in lowercase.

Here's the code:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'worksans';
  src: url('work_sans_regular/worksans-regular.woff2')  format('woff2'),
       url('work_sans_regular/worksans-regular.woff') format('woff'),
       url('work_sans_regular/worksans-regular.eot') format('eot');
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style: normal;
}

html {
  font-family: 'worksans';
}
```

When I use the font only the Latin characters have the font. Non-latin characters have the fallback font.

Comment: What character is it you're trying to add? And is the character actually displayed in the front-end (just not in the desired font)?

Comment: Lithuanian characters. They work if you install the font's .ttf file on your machine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using unicode-range maybe thats the issue
[This](http://johndyer.name/using-css-to-display-fonts-for-greek-and-hebrew-but-not-english/) should help

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.